# Wordpress User restriction without any plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently stuck with a problem regarding user authentication in Wordpress, and i think i need some guidance in how you would solve this. So any feedback is much appreciated.

First of all, my setup is pretty basic and i create pages and posts with ACF - I try to minimize the use of Wordpress plugins since 99% it brings a messy experience and functionality.

**My question:**

I want to create a simple Wordpress "application", where a user that is signed in:

1. Belongs to a Company.
2. Can only read assigned Reports (CPT).

*Every page and post are restricted to logged in users only.*

*The users reports (CPT) is only shown in the frontend - a user (company) should not have access to wp-admin*

I believe the easiest way to do this would be to make a multisite, creating a subdomain:

**company**.website.com/reports

My concern is that this would eventually create a lot of WP installations and if i update one of my Custom fields (ACF), i would need to update this on each installation.

How would you solve this issue? Would the subdomain be the right solution?

Thank you for helping out.

Comment: This is more of an opinion, but if you're looking for ideas, why not leverage the default WP roles... As it relates to ACF, you can programmatically enable / add custom fields in your php.  As the code updates, so will your custom fields without having to manage in each instance. You're on the right track with the multisite route.